# wxpanel hide/show and wxwebview

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

My frame (Python 3) has the following structure:

```
MyFormClass
- Sizer1
--Panel 1
---Sizer 2
---WxWebView
---WxButton
```

WxButton has the LeftDown function:

```
def goPoint(self,e ):
    self.m_panel1.Hide()
    self.m_panel1.Show()
    self.Layout()
```

After executing of this code i have a gray screen instead wxwebview. How to show wxwebview?